# Using wildcards in phrases with Elasticsearch Query String Query

Tags: elasticsearch

Using the wildcard operator, I can match terms starting with some value:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "subject:cell*"
        }
    }
}
```

The `subject` field here is a `keyword` field (non-analyzed). This works fine, but I cannot figure out how to find terms starting with, say, "cellular contr". Trying double quotes did not yield the expected results:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "subject:\"cellular contr*\""
        }
    }
}
```

Note: phrase search works fine with exact matches, just not with the wildcard. My guess is that the star is not interpreted as a wildcard operator inside the double quotes. Is that correct? And is there any other way to use the wildcard operator with a phrase?

Note: I have to use [Query String Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-dsl-query-string-query), since the query is coming from user input.

(I know I could resort to regexp, but would prefer not to)

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the custom analyzer as pointed by Hemed, you need to do search as below -

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "subject:cellular\\ contr*"
        }
    }
}
```

Found it after a lot of research and tries!

Comment: Thank you for this hint! "\\ " is telling elastic that it IS a space in the phrase and you can (or must) omit the quotes of the searched string.

Comment: Thanks for the details, hard to point any post regarding this

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** 
Define custom analyzer for searching:-

```
settings:
   index:
     analysis:
       analyzer:
         keyword_analyzer:
           type: custom
           tokenizer: keyword
           filter:
             - lowercase
```

Found out that you need to use [Prefix Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) in this case, because Query String Query always segments on spaces during parsing.

But since you are using `lowecase filter` in this field and Prefix Query does not support analyzer, you would have to lowercase user input before appending it to the query.

New query becomes:-

```
   {
        "query": {
            "prefix" : {
                "subject" : "cellular contr"
            }
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, you can use [Match Phrase Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html) which supports analyzer.

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase_prefix" : {
            "subject" : {
                 "query" : "Cellular contr",
                  "analyzer" : "keyword_analyzer",
                  "max_expansions" : 100
                 }
              }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Would work if I didn't need a phrase query. But I don't want the query "cellular contr*" to match, say, "control of cellular material", which is why I'm indexing the field as `keyword`.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. Is it correct that you want to search for query string "cellular contr" and get a result for "control of cellular material" in the field `subject` of type `keyword` which is `not analyzed`?

Comment: No, if I search for "cellular contr", I want it to match "cellular control", but not "control of cellular material". So what I want is really `subject:/cellular contr.*/`, but without using regexp.

Comment: Please see my edit. I think you would have to specify custom search analyzer when searching in this particular field.

Comment: Seems like it gives exactly the same result. Probably still interpreted as `(subject:cellular) OR (contr*)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "subject:"cellular contr*",
            "split_on_whitespace" : false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The default value is `false`, so setting it explicitly to false shouldn't make any difference. But I tried just in case, and it's interpreted as "(subject:cellular) OR (contr*)", not what I want. I also tried playing with `analyze_wildcard` and `auto_generate_phrase_queries` without success (the documentation is a bit thin on exactly what they do, though)